# Pass an argument to higher level event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's assume I created one div inside of another one like this:

```
<div class='parent'>
    Parent
    <div class='chid'>
        Child
    </div>
</div>
```

And a javascript / jQuery script:

```
// Parent click event handler
$(document).on('click', '.parent', function(e){
    console.log("Parent clicked");
    console.log(myVar); //               <--- undefined obviously.
});

// Child click event handler
$(document).on('click', '.child', function(e){
    var myVar = "This is some string.";
    console.log("Child clicked");
});
```

Now what I want to achieve is to pass the value of myVar from child click event handler to the parent click event handler, so that I can use that variable in the higher-level event handler?

Comment: Well do you know about scoping of variables?  That is your problem.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? There is probably better ways to do this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to set then pass to parent? there are different ways of doing this depending on the situation

Comment: If you just want to share myvar, just move it outside of the child, and then due to scoping rules, both click handlers will have access to it.  If you want to avoid globals here, just place inside an IFFE, etc, to create a local scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, without having to make `myVar` global, is this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#parent", function(e) {
    console.log('clicked parent!', e.myVar); // if child was clicked, myVar will have value
});

$(document).on("click", "#child", function(e) {
    var myVar = 12;
    e.myVar = myVar; // attach de variable to the event
    console.log('clicked child!');
});
```

You attach a value to the event that bubbles up the DOM, so you receive the value ONLY when the inner DIV is clicked.

I'm sure that, depending on what you wnat to achieve, there are better ways to do this, but, without more info, this should work.

Hope this helps you.